# How to avoid haxis/xaxis year duplicate with date format in Google Line Chart?

Tags: charts, google-visualization

I draw google line chart with a massive json data from AJAX. The data looks like:

```
[
  [new Date(2013, 02), 1324, null, 8902],
  [new Date(2013, 05), null, 1256, 8902],
  [new Date(2013, 07), 1324, 1256, null],
  [new Date(2014, 02), 1324, null, 8902],
  [new Date(2014, 08), null, 1256, 8902],
  [new Date(2015, 01), 1324, 1256, null],
  [new Date(2015, 09), 1324, null, 8902],
  ...
]
```

The data is huge, so I decide to show year only on haxis/xaxis.

```
{
  haxis: {
    format: 'yyyy'
  }
}
```

But the problem comes, the xaxis/haxis appears duplicated years like:

2013 2013 2013 2014 2014 2015 2015.

I know it because the month are different. But is there anyway to remove the duplicated years? By the way, the data is dynamic. So I can not hardcode the ticks.

Answer (score 1):

the `ticks` can be built dynamically from the data

use data table method --> `getColumnRange(colIndex)`

this returns an object with `min` & `max` properties for the column,
which can be used to build the ticks

see following working snippet for an example...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      [new Date(2013, 02), 1324, null, 8902],
      [new Date(2013, 05), null, 1256, 8902],
      [new Date(2013, 07), 1324, 1256, null],
      [new Date(2014, 02), 1324, null, 8902],
      [new Date(2014, 08), null, 1256, 8902],
      [new Date(2015, 01), 1324, 1256, null],
      [new Date(2015, 09), 1324, null, 8902]
    ], true);

    var dateRange = data.getColumnRange(0);
    var oneYear = (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365.25);
    var ticksAxisH = [];
    var year = -1;
    for (var i = dateRange.min.getTime(); i <= dateRange.max.getTime(); i = i + oneYear) {
      var tick = new Date(i);
      if (year !== tick.getFullYear()) {
        ticksAxisH.push({
          v: tick,
          f: tick.getFullYear().toString()
        });
        year = tick.getFullYear();
      }
    }

    var options = {
      hAxis: {
        ticks: ticksAxisH
      }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart($('#chart').get(0));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  },
  packages:['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
```